# Determine if the integral $\int^{2}_{0} \frac{\sec^2(x)}{x\sqrt{x}}dx$ converges or diverges?

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Determine if the integral $$\int^{2}_{0} \dfrac{\sec^2(x)}{x\sqrt{x}}dx$$ converges or diverges?

I know that it is positive on this interval so I can use the convergence/divergence theorem.

This integral has to discontinues, $x=0, x=\pi/2$, and so this makes me think that it diverges. I have to find a smaller function. I have trouble here.

How do I make the numerator $\sec^2(x)$ smaller? I can make the denominator bigger by just making it $x$, or $x^2$, but I need help with the numerator.

Comment: There's a bad discontinuity at $\pi/2.$

Comment: Sorry I meant to say $\pi/2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prefer to use this:

$$\frac{\sec^2(x)}{x^{3/2}}\ge\frac1{x^{3/2}}$$

It thus follows that

$$\int_0^2\frac1{x^{3/2}}\ dx=\frac{-2}{x^{1/2}}\bigg|_0^2$$

And we immediately conclude from there.

Comment: How did you bound the $\sec^2(x)?$

Comment: That's not quite right as you've glossed over the problem at $\pi/2.$

Comment: @KSplitX Well, it is useful to recall some trig bounds: $$|\cos(x)|\le1\implies\left|\frac1{\cos(x)}\right|\ge1$$

Comment: @zhw., but the problem there is immaterial if it blows up at 0.

Comment: @zhw. How does that affect anything?

Comment: True but why do want to have irrelevant errors in your solution?

Comment: It's not an error.  It is always greater.

Comment: @zhw. There are no errors.  It is always true that for $x\ge0$, then $$\frac{\sec^2(x)}{x^{3/2}}\ge\frac1{x^{3/2}}$$ And we can conclude on that alone.

Comment: I have a question. If the original function has discontinues at 2 points, then do we have to split the integral up at those 2 points when doing it for the one simply beautiful art answered? Or no?

Comment: @KSplitX No, since the discontinuity at $\pi/2$ has $\sec^2(x)\to+\infty$ from both sides, hence my bound is still valid for a comparison.  If we had $\sec(x)$ instead, then one side would be negative and one positive, whereupon splitting the integral into two would be attractive to use.

Comment: Look, just replace the $2$ with a $1$ will ya?

Comment: @zhw. What do you mean?  Could you elaborate?

Comment: By the way @SimplyBeautifulArt, I think you have to take the limit as $x \to 0^+$ since it is undefined at $x=0$, (the function you have above)

Comment: @KSplitX Yes, of course, but the conclusion is still clear.  :-)

Comment: Ok thanks. I don't know what the argument going on in the comment section is but I think this is right answer. Thank you

Comment: :-) No problem.  Just some minor confusions but its all fine @KSplitX

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt  Yes, you are right. Now that I look at this again today, I see my comments were nonsense. I don't know what I was thinking. My bad, apologies.

Comment: @zhw. No problem man.  I had my own faults in many ways yesterday too :P

Answer (score 1):

$\sec x = \frac{1}{\cos x} = \frac{1}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - x\right)}$ is asymptotically $\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2} - x}$ as $x \to \frac{\pi}{2}$.

But $$\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x}\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - x\right)^2}$$

clearly blows up too fast as $x \to \frac{\pi}{2}$, so there is no convergence.

By the way, Simply Beautiful Art's solution is probably easier. It's just that this function has $2$ (bad) singularities, so we can choose which one to work with.